# EthereumProvider from @walletconnect/ethereum-provider not seeing my Infura project

Tags: react, infura, walletconnect, websocket, nextjs

I'm having trouble with getting EthereumProvider to connect via the Infura API key. I use it in my connection logic like this:

```typescript
const provider = await EthereumProvider.init({
                    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INFURA_ID!,
                    showQrModal: true,
                    optionalChains: [1, 5, 11155111],
                })
                await provider.enable()
```

After clicking the connect button that calls this method, I get this error:

```
Error: WebSocket connection closed abnormally with code: 3000 (Authorization error: Project not found)
```

The env variable is being retrieved fine, as I checked it in console.log, and also tried hardcoding the projectId, still won't work. I'm working on localhost, and I checked the Infura API key to have active endpoints for Mainnet, Goerli, and Sepolia (the chains I specify).

I've checked all the issues people had with this EthereumProvider, but no one had an issue like this one. I would very much appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What do you see if you do curl `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{YOUR_INFURA_ID} -X POST -H “Content-Type: application/json” -d ‘{“jsonrpc”:“2.0”,“method”:“eth_blockNumber”,“params”: [],“id”:1}’` in th terminal?

Comment: @MilaA I get `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32002,"message":"rejected due to project ID settings"}}` if I run this from the terminal

Comment: Oleh, check your Infura settings, you might want to whitelist the localhost domain in order for this to work

Comment: I've tried that before, it won't help. I still get the same message from the terminal and the website. I've added it as `http://localhost:3000/`, `http://localhost/`, `localhost`, `localhost:3000`, `*my ip*`, `*my ip*:3000` and `http://*my ip*:3000/` to the allowlist's origins

Comment: Can you temporarily switch to an HTTP endpoint instead of a WebSocket endpoint as the comment suggests here (https://community.infura.io/t/whitelisting-problem-rejected-due-to-project-id-settings/1365/4)?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://community.infura.io/t/what-means-rejected-due-to-project-id-settings/543/3

Comment: And *finally* this one: https://community.infura.io/t/what-means-rejected-due-to-project-id-settings/543/15

Comment: I've checked all the threads mentioned and still don't know how can I use it in my case. I can't switch to an HTTP endpoint because Wallet Connect `EthereumProvider` does not provide that as an option, as far as I've seen on the documentation, which is a bit outdated anyway. About the other ones, I'm sending a request straight from the terminal (as you suggested for troubleshooting), what does `whitelist the contract address` mean in this context? Also, the other options I have configured as suggested. Sorry if the questions may be dumb, as I'm new to the space and just doing my second project

Comment: See https://docs.infura.io/networks/ethereum/how-to/secure-a-project/use-an-allowlist#contract-addresses on how to allowlist contracts for further interaction with Infura's endpoints.

Comment: I've added that address to allowlist and tried running `curl https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{MY_INFURA_ID} \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -X POST \
    -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_getBalance","params":["0xfe05a3e72235c9f92fd9f2282f41a8154d6d342b", "latest"]}'`, but I still got `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32002,"message":"rejected due to project ID settings"}}` back...

Comment: Hmm, then I suggest you to try posting an issue here: https://community.infura.io/

Comment: Something might be misconfigured in your project's settings. There've been a lot of posts with the same 32002 Error code issue.

Comment: I'll check them out, and if I won't be able to find a solution — will post this issue on the Infura forum. Thanks!

Comment: @OlehYatskiv Did you try using a project ID created in the walletconnect.com? It is a `@walletconnect` project so it makes sense to use that instead of infura's ID.

Comment: Yeah, I tried registering my project there, but it seems that walletconnect doesn't work with localhost like that.